# How to Compare columns of two tables using Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compare two tables() by reading as DataFrames. And for each common column in those tables using concatenation of a primary key say order_id with other columns like order_date, order_name, order_event.

The Scala Code I am using

```
val primary_key=order_id
for (i <- commonColumnsList){
      val column_name = i
      val tempDataFrameForNew = newDataFrame.selectExpr(s"concat($primaryKey,$i) as concatenated")
      val tempDataFrameOld = oldDataFrame.selectExpr(s"concat($primaryKey,$i) as concatenated")

      //Get those records which aren common in both old/new tables
      matchCountCalculated = tempDataFrameForNew.intersect(tempDataFrameOld)
      //Get those records which aren't common in both old/new tables
      nonMatchCountCalculated = tempDataFrameOld.unionAll(tempDataFrameForNew).except(matchCountCalculated)

      //Total Null/Non-Null Counts in both old and new tables.
      nullsCountInNewDataFrame = newDataFrame.select(s"$i").filter(x => x.isNullAt(0)).count().toInt
      nullsCountInOldDataFrame = oldDataFrame.select(s"$i").filter(x => x.isNullAt(0)).count().toInt
      nonNullsCountInNewDataFrame = newDFCount - nullsCountInNewDataFrame
      nonNullsCountInOldDataFrame = oldDFCount - nullsCountInOldDataFrame

      //Put the result for a given column in a Seq variable, later convert it to Dataframe.
      tempSeq = tempSeq :+ Row(column_name, matchCountCalculated.toString, nonMatchCountCalculated.toString, (nullsCountInNewDataFrame - nullsCountInOldDataFrame).toString,
       (nonNullsCountInNewDataFrame - nonNullsCountInOldDataFrame).toString)
}
     // Final Step: Create DataFrame using Seq and some Schema.
     spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(tempSeq), schema)
```

The above code is working fine for a medium set of Data, but as the number of Columns and Records increases in my New & Old Table, the execution time is increasing. Any sort of advice is appreciated.
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:
1. Outer join the old and new dataframe on priamary key
`joined_df = df_old.join(df_new, primary_key, "outer")`
2. Cache it if you possibly can. This will save you a lot of time
3. Now you can iterate over columns and compare columns using spark functions (`.isNull` for not matched, `==` for matched etc)

```scala
for (col <- df_new.columns){
  val matchCount = df_joined.filter(df_new[col].isNotNull && df_old[col].isNotNull).count()
  val nonMatchCount = ...
}
```

This should be considerably faster, especially when you can cache your dataframe. If you can't it might be  a good idea so save the joined df to disk in order to avoid a shuffle each time

Comment: Hey Paul, Thank you for the Answer. But I have a little confusion, or maybe my Question is not framed properly. If I do the Outer join the columns in DF1 and DF2 shouldn't match except for the primary key, isn't it?
But in my Old/New DataFrames I've the same column Names. And I am interested in finding the difference for a column that is available in both DataFrames.

Comment: No I mean an outer join on the primary key column `val joined_df = df_new.join(df_old, primary_key, "outer")`

Comment: Sorry Sir my Bad, Okay so a full outer join on the primary key and then 
iterate as <primaryKey,Col1>,<primaryKey,Col2>,<primaryKey,Col3>.
Please correct my understanding.

Comment: I've added some pseudocode for the iteration. The idea is still to iterate over the columns only (except for primary_key col). You don't need to concat the key with the column